# Excel Macro to merge duplicate cells and sum corresponding data more efficiently

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, which merges duplicate cells and then sums the corresponding cells in the other columns. So for example if I had:

```
mike  651
mike  115
john  380
bob   225
bob   200
```

the resulting output would be:

```
mike  766
john  380
bob   425
```

The code works well for smaller datasets, but when I try to use it on my larger datasets (around 500,000 rows) the code is extremely slow (Takes over an hour to run). How can I edit my code to make it efficient enough to merge the duplicates and sum the corresponding data of a very large dataset quickly?

```
Sub mergeDups()

lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Resize(1)
With Application.WorksheetFunction

    For iRow = lastRow - 1 To 2 Step -1
        Do While Cells(iRow, 1) = Cells(iRow + 1, 1)
            LastCol = r(r.Count).Column
            SumCol = LastCol + 1
               For iCol = 2 To SumCol
               Cells(iRow, iCol) = .Sum(Range(Cells(iRow, iCol), Cells(iRow + 1, iCol)))
               Next iCol
            Rows(iRow + 1).delete
        Loop
    Next iRow

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sums Columns A:B and places result in D1 and down.

```
Sub mergeDups()
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Range("D1").Consolidate Sources:=Array("R1C1:R" & lastRow & "C2"), LeftColumn:=True, Function:=xlSum
End Sub
```

Taskes about a second on my end with 50,000 lines

Answer (score 2):

Just for a quick victory - you can do this:

```
Sub mergeDups()

    call OnStart

    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Resize(1)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction

        For iRow = lastRow - 1 To 2 Step -1
            Do While Cells(iRow, 1) = Cells(iRow + 1, 1)
                LastCol = r(r.Count).Column
                SumCol = LastCol + 1
                   For iCol = 2 To SumCol
                   Cells(iRow, iCol) = .Sum(Range(Cells(iRow, iCol), Cells(iRow + 1, iCol)))
                   Next iCol
                Rows(iRow + 1).delete
            Loop
        Next iRow

    End With
    call OnEnd

End Sub

Public Sub OnStart()

    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub

Public Sub OnEnd()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

End Sub
```

Furthermore - what are LastRow and iRow? How are they declared? If they are variants, then make them long. If it is still slow, then note which rows should be deleted and delete them in one step.

Answer (score 2):

No loops needed:

```
Sub merge()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    Set rng = .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    rng.Offset(, 50).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C1,RC[-51],C2)"
    rng.Value = rng.Offset(, 50).Value
    rng.Offset(, 50).ClearContents
    rng.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlGuess
End With

End Sub
```